# Keeping lists horizontal at all times

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble trying to keep a list horizontal, I haven't been able to find it anywhere and white-space: nowrap doesn't work. I don't mind the 4 items being underneath the text after a certain screen size but it's gotta be horizontal still, in this case it goes vertical and I can't figure out why, there's my fiddle try out yourself by re-sizing and you'll what I mean!

```
<div class="menu">
    <h2>
       This is a text
    </h2>
     <ul>
        <li><a>Test1</a></li>
        <li><a>Test2</a></li>
        <li><a>Test3</a></li>
        <li><a>Test4</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qpod1yo/1/)

Please only css or html fixes!

Thank you!

Comment: You need to pick up some more technical terms. *"Keep a list horizontal"* can mean more than one thing in web design. It might mean you want all the list items in one line or it might mean you don't want the list items to wrap their contents. Well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
h2 {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <h2>
    This is a text
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Test1</a></li>
      <li><a>Test2</a></li>
      <li><a>Test3</a></li>
      <li><a>Test4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**float is not your friend**

Just change your ul and li styles to looks as follows:

```
ul {
  margin-right: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: And how does your proposed solution keep all `li`s on one line?

Comment: Run it and looks like it works ;)

Comment: It does work! thank you for posting, I don't know why Andrei voted it -1. My problem was the float, didn't know that it would be a problem.

Comment: I tend to believe [flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/2qpod1yo/3/) is what should have been used here.

Comment: I agree with @AndreiGheorghiu but, the example puts in the wrong place the title when the screen is too small. And flexbox is not full supported in all browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: It has better support than `box-shadow`, Aguardientico. Don't tell me you're not using `box-shadow`.

Comment: `box-shadow` is supported in almost most browsers... from so far long time